# How to get the slideshow behind the menu

Tags: html, css

I have megamenu in the header and content slider which fades using html5 and css3. When I click the menu, i get the submenu displayed. But what the problem here is, the content and image of the slider is displayed on the megamenu as shown in the screenshot.
[image: Megamenu with Slideshow]

Here is the code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qCeHc

When I hover on menu, slideshow is overlapping the submenu. Help me sort out what I am missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add z-index value to the following.

```
#nav ul.subs {
background-color: #333;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
color: #333333;
display: none;
left: 0;
padding: 2%;
position: absolute;
top: 54px;
width: 96%;
z-index:999;
}
```